# Bash script executes fine on its own, but not with cron

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, cron, cron-task

I type

> crontab -e

my crontab looks like

```
*/1 * * * * /home/sara/Desktop/kioskscripts/reloadpage.sh >> /home/sara/Desktop/kioskscripts/logfile.log
```

logfile is created in /kioskscripts but remains empty.

reloadpage.sh looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
/usr/bin/xdotool key F5
```

> sh reloadpage.sh

works as expected and simulates f5 being pressed 5 seconds after execution.

Comment: Why do you expect `xdotool` to write anything to standard output? Or, better said, *what* do you expect it to write?

Comment: I expected that if executing reloadpage.sh threw an error, that would be written to the logfile. That part doesn't matter as much as getting the script to execute properly once a minute though.

Comment: If executing reloadpage.sh throws an error, the error will be written to stderr, not stdout. So you'd need to use `2>>` to capture that. (However, I don't think `xdotool` would give you an error if the keystroke event is not handled by the target window.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program executed by `cron` does not have an active window, so you would need to explicitly specify which window you want the keystroke to be sent to using the `--window` option.

You can get the window id of your currently active window with `xdotool getactivewindow` and then use that number in an `xdotool` command. Or you can use `xdotool search` with various options to find the window you want to direct the keystroke to. Read `man xdotool` for the various search options. (You can do that in a single command: `xdotool search --name Foo key F5` will send F5 to a window with `FOO` in its name.)

But that will only work if the indicated window accepts the events, and many windows don't.

Comment: Chrome accepts keystrokes but only when in focus, which is fine for my purposes. Wouldn't have found this without you, ty.

Comment: @BrianHotopp: You can add `windowraise` to the xdotool commands, also. But I think that is quite disruptive to the user experience :)